# find repeatable string position in array

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I cannot get repeatable string postion in array. My code like this:

```
var startDates : [String] = ["06/11/2018", "16/11/2018", "26/11/2018", "06/11/2018"]
var nomor : [Int] = []
for date in startDates {
        if startDates.contains(where: {
            $0.range(of: "06/11/2018", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        }) == true {
            let nomornya = startDates.index(of: "06/11/2018")!
            nomor.append(nomornya)
        }
    }
    print("nomornya:\(nomor)")
```

it result :

```
nomornya:[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to get like this:

```
nomornya:[0, 3]
```

What is the correct code to do that?

Comment: What would be the output if there is more than one date that is duplicate?

Comment: the function is to get all event from calendar, which one date can have multiple event title, so I must get the position

Comment: What are you trying to do here? These strings look like dates but you are dealing with them as strings. It looks like there is possibly a much better way of doing what you’re trying to do.

Comment: What is the expected output for `["06/11/2018", "16/11/2018", "26/11/2018", "06/11/2018", "16/11/2018"]`?

Comment: @Sweeper the result must be [0,3]

Comment: @Sarimin can you explain why [0,3] for that too?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, because it can be use as title position, which shown in the next page as tableView list. it did not show all title, only title with spesific position

Comment: What is **it**?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri at that example title[0] and title[3] only

Comment: So only one date is always compared with your array, no matter how many other duplicate dates are there correct?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the indices of the items matching a specific date, so filter the indices:

```
let startDates = ["06/11/2018", "16/11/2018", "26/11/2018", "06/11/2018"]
let nomor = startDates.indices.filter{ startDates[$0] == "06/11/2018" } // [0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = "06/11/2018"
var matchingIndices = [Int]()
for (index, startDate) in startDates.enumerated() {
    if date == startDate {
        matchingIndices.append(index)
    }
}
```

You want to iterate once through the list noting the matching indices. This should match your expected output.

Comment: this one is correct too, but longer code